# How to call DialogFragment from RecyclerView.ViewHolder (with interface implement)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I saw few related questions about this kind of situation, but couldn't find any solution, so my problem goes like this.

I have tabLayout which hold's 4 fragments, Im delivering data to user in frag number 3 (catalog), this frag hold recyclerView for cardView im trying to implement onclicklistner for card which will invoke dialogFragment, I understand the most efficient way to do so, is using interface for the viewHolder, i face one problem the **recyclerView adapter constructor**.

Here is the the catalog frag:

```
public class CatalogFragment extends Fragment implements CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

private FloatingActionButton mSharedFab;
private List<MyProducts> productsList;

//Creating Views
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

private CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener;//////LISTNER FOR DIALOG???

//Volley Request 
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

//request counter 
private int requestCount = 1;
private static final String URL_INDEX = "http://myserverip/product.php";
//Tag values to read from json
public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "product_img";
public static final String TAG_PRODUCT_SN = "product_serial_num";
public static final String TAG_PRODUCT_TITLE = "product_title";
public static final String TAG_PRODUCT_PRICE = "product_price";
public static final String TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION = "product_description";

public CatalogFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_catalog, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
    itemAnimator.setAddDuration(1000);
    itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(1000);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);

    //Initializing our product list
    productsList = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    // fetch data
    getData();



    //initialize adapter

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(listener, productsList, getActivity());
    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view ;
}
 @Override
public void onItemClicked(View v) {
    DialogAddToCartFragment df= new DialogAddToCartFragment();
    df.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
}
```

the adapter instantiated with 3 params, with customadapter.

the customAdapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(View v);
}

private OnItemClickListener listener;
//Image loader inst for image
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

private Context context;
public Snackbar snackbar;
String title;
//List  all products
List<MyProducts> myProducts;

public CustomAdapter( OnItemClickListener listener, List<MyProducts> myProducts, Context context)
{
    super();
    this.listener = listener;
    this.myProducts = myProducts;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.product_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if( myProducts != null) {
        MyProducts myProducts1 = myProducts.get(position);
        imageLoader = ImageVolley.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(myProducts1.getProductImage(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.android_store_log, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
        title = myProducts1.getProductTitle();
        //Showing data to the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(myProducts1.getProductImage(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewProductTitle.setText(myProducts1.getProductTitle());
        holder.textViewProductDescription.setText(myProducts1.getProductDescription());
        holder.textViewProductSerialNumber.setText(myProducts1.getProductSn());
        holder.textViewProductPrice.setText(myProducts1.getProductPrice());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myProducts.size();
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //Views
    public NetworkImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewProductTitle;
    public TextView textViewProductDescription;
    public TextView textViewProductSerialNumber;
    public TextView textViewProductPrice;

    //Initializing Views
    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewProduct);
        textViewProductTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductTitle);
        textViewProductDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductDescription);
        textViewProductSerialNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductSerialNumber);
        textViewProductPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductPrice);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClicked(v);/////////DIALOG LISTENER????
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the DialogFragment:

```
public class DialogAddToCartFragment extends DialogFragment {



@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_add_to_cart, new LinearLayout(getActivity()), false);

    // Retrieve layout elements
    //TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_title);

    // Set values
    //title.setText("Not perfect yet");

    // Build dialog
    Dialog builder = new Dialog(getActivity());
    builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));
    builder.setContentView(view);
    return builder;

}
```

}

As i click on card i get program closed :(

Here is the log:

```
07-12 08:42:22.685 2808-2808/com.example.get2i.androidstore E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.get2i.androidstore, PID: 2808
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.get2i.androidstore.CustomAdapter$OnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.get2i.androidstore.CustomAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:102)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

With what should i instntiate the CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener in the catalogfrag? Any advice would be appriciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what should i instntiate the CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener
>   listener in the catalogfrag?

Because   forget to initialize `listener` object before passing it to `CustomAdapter` class constructor. do it as:

```
listener=this;
adapter = new CustomAdapter(listener, productsList, getActivity());
...
```

Comment: Creating a listener object is completely irrelevant at this point. You should just pass `this` in the constructor..

Comment: @vguzzi: Good suggestion, my answer is according to problem which OP is posted with question`onItemClicked(android.view.View)' on a null object reference` because `listener  is null` . and your answer is also Right.Thanks

Comment: dunno why, but it dosent let me to pass this in the cons, been trying this too.

Comment: @2Stoned: Fragment is implementing `OnItemClickListener ` so we call pass both this or CatalogFragment.this

Comment: @2Stoned: which error u are getting when passing `this` ?

Answer (score 2):

instantiate the fragmentManager in the activity itself,

### MyActivity.java

```
 `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 adapter = new CustomAdapter(productsList, fragmentManager);`
```

---

### CustomAdapter.java

```
 `CustomAdapter implements MyClickListner{
 CustomAdapter(Arraylist<MyProduct>productsList, FragmentManager 
 fragmentManager) {
      this.productList = productsList;
      this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
 }

 `@override
  clickFunction(){
     Fragment myFragment= new MyFilterFragment();
     ((MyFilterFragment) myFragment).show(this.fragmentManager,"tag");
  }`
```

---

### MyClickListener.java

```
`public interface MyClickListener(){
   public clickFunction();
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

call this method in `onBindViewHolder` on `itemView`'s click listener

```
public void showDialogFragment(View view){
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = DialogFragment.newInstance("Delete item","Are you sure you want to delete this item ?",R.drawable.cancel);
        AppCompatActivity activity = ((AppCompatActivity)view.getContext());
        dialogFragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(),null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

Just change this in your CatalogFragment

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(listener, productsList, getActivity());
```

To

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, productsList, getActivity());
```

You're getting NPE because you are passing null reference of your listener

Comment: i cant the customAdpater asks for OnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in an empty listener, not the one which you have implemented in your `Fragment` instance.

Change this line;

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(listener, productsList, getActivity());
```

to this;

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, productsList, getActivity());
```

and delete your listener variable.